# No odometry/filtered output from robot_localization

Tags: navigation, robot-localization, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

I'm trying to fuse IMU and a camera estimation but I receive no output through /odometry/filtered. If I try with IMU alone, it does send infromation through that topic, but when I try with the camera estimation,I have no response from the EKF node.

The camera sends a PoseWithCovarianceStamped message that tells the displacement between the previous frame and the current one in the UAV coordinate frame (called erlecopter/imu_link):

```
  geometry_msgs::PoseWithCovarianceStamped pub_msg;

  pub_msg.header.seq=seq;
  pub_msg.header.stamp=msg->header.stamp;
  pub_msg.header.frame_id="erlecopter/imu_link";

  pub_msg.pose.pose.position.x=tras.at<double>(0);
  pub_msg.pose.pose.position.y=tras.at<double>(1);
  pub_msg.pose.pose.position.z=tras.at<double>(2);

  pub_msg.pose.pose.orientation=Euler2Quat(angles);
  
  pub_msg.pose.covariance=Covariance_default;

  Pub_estimation.publish(pub_msg);
```

where, the publisher node has been defined like this:

```
ros::Publisher Pub_estimation;
Pub_estimation=nh.advertise<geometry_msgs::PoseWithCovarianceStamped>("Camera_estimation",1);
```

This message is properly as I have seen thanks to rostopic echo.

My parameters file for the EKF node is like this (for the camera only fusion):

```
frequency: 1
sensor_timeout: 2
two_d_mode: false
transform_time_offset: 0.0
transform_timeout: 0.0
print_diagnostics: true
debug: false
publish_tf: true
publish_acceleration: false

map_frame: map             
odom_frame: odom           
base_link_frame: erlecopter/imu_link  
world_frame: odom 


pose0: Camera_estimation
pose0_config:  [true, true, true,
               true, true, true,
               false, false, false,
               false,  false,  false,
               false,  false,  false]

process_noise_covariance: [0.05, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0.05, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0.06, 0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0.03, 0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0.03, 0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.06, 0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.025, 0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0.025, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0.04, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0.01, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0.01, 0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0.02, 0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0.01, 0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.01, 0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.015]
initial_estimate_covariance: [1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9,  0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     1e-9,  0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     1e-9,  0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     1e-9, 0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    1e-9, 0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    1e-9]
```

Do you have any idea why no data is being published published in /odometry/filtered ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/351790/no-odometry/filtered-output-from-robot_localization/) by [Aquas](https://answers.ros.org/users/53505/aquas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2020-05-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [schizzz8](https://answers.ros.org/users/3511/schizzz8/) on 2020-05-08**:
The frame_id of the PoseWithCovarianceStamped message seems to be that of the IMU, is this intended?

**Comment by [schizzz8](https://answers.ros.org/users/3511/schizzz8/) on 2020-05-08**:
Is "Camera_estimation" the name of the topic where you publish the pose?

**Comment by [Aquas](https://answers.ros.org/users/53505/aquas/) on 2020-05-08**:
Yes, Camera_estimation is the topic name, and I have modified its data so that instead of being with respect to the camera frame, it is with respect to the IMU one. That's why I use the same frame_id for both IMU and the camera estimation. I use those two commands:

```
ros::Publisher Pub_estimation;

Pub_estimation=nh.advertise<geometry_msgs::PoseWithCovarianceStamped>("Camera_estimation",1);
```

Do I upload the full code?

**Comment by [schizzz8](https://answers.ros.org/users/3511/schizzz8/) on 2020-05-08**:
If on that topic you're publishing the pose of the camera the `frame_id` should be a global frame like odom or something similar

**Comment by [Aquas](https://answers.ros.org/users/53505/aquas/) on 2020-05-09**:
It is not the pose of the camera but the displacement of the UAV between the previous measure and the current one (it is extracted from a camera but it is in the UAV frame of reference).

**Comment by [schizzz8](https://answers.ros.org/users/3511/schizzz8/) on 2020-05-11**:
mmm...usually is better to express these quantities in global frames. Btw, check that the tf tree is ok, i.e. that there is a connection between the odom frame and the imu_link. You can use [rqt_tf_tree](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_tf_tree).

**Comment by [Aquas](https://answers.ros.org/users/53505/aquas/) on 2020-05-11**:
rqt_tf_tree says no data received. I have tried with rqt_graph and this is what I get:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WRko6uJ14IoyjLEwE2OM-MtrAciakddG/view?usp=sharing
( I cannot upload photos :( )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is very likely that you don't have a valid TF tree, i.e. the imu_link is not connected to the odom frame.

To double-check run:

```
rosrun tf tf_echo odom erlecopter/imu_link
```

**EDIT**

What you are missing is the part that publishes a TF between the odom and the camera frame.

If, as you say:

> The camera sends a
> PoseWithCovarianceStamped message that
> tells the displacement between the
> previous frame and the current one

Then, what you have to do is to integrate over time the displacements to obtain the global transformation between the camera and a fixed reference frame.

---

Originally posted by [schizzz8](https://answers.ros.org/users/3511/schizzz8/) with karma: 183 on 2020-05-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Aquas](https://answers.ros.org/users/53505/aquas/) on 2020-05-11**:
Failure at 1589196125.549205710
Exception thrown:"odom" passed to lookupTransform argument target_frame does not exist.
The current list of frames is:

And it continues like this until I do Ctl+C, without outputting any frame

**Comment by [schizzz8](https://answers.ros.org/users/3511/schizzz8/) on 2020-05-11**:
Fix the TF tree and you will be done!

**Comment by [Aquas](https://answers.ros.org/users/53505/aquas/) on 2020-05-13**:
I'll have to look further into how to create that TF tree, because I have no idea

**Comment by [hashirzahir](https://answers.ros.org/users/53034/hashirzahir/) on 2020-05-14**:
Load a URDF and use the robot_state_publisher to publish the static transforms. Or just use a simple launch file and add TF2 static_transform_publisher between base_link and imu_link